# 2次元連想配列のwhile文に関して

Tags: php

2次元連想配列をwhileでforeachと同じように表示させたいですが上手くいきません。
方法を教えていたください。

```
$list = array(
    array(
        'id'=>1,
        'name'=>'a'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>2,
        'name'=>'b'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>3,
        'name'=>'c'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>4,
        'name'=>'d'
    )
);

while ($value = current($list)) {
    print key($list) . ':' . $value . "\n";
    next($list);
}

echo 'foreach'."\n";
foreach($list as $key => $value){
    echo 'ID:'.$value['id'].'name:'.$value['name'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: `print key($list) . ':' . $value . "\n";` とするのではなく、`foreach` の場合と同じ `echo 'ID:'.$value['id'].' name:'.$value['name'].'<br>';` で良いのではないでしょうか。。。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。